# How can I bind a combobox field of a databound object to a datasource and still allow nulls?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, null, datasource

I have a form databound to a customer object, and one of the fields is a nullable int representing a "type".  This is displayed as a combobox, and the combobox is bound to the "Types" table.

When a customer with a null type is loaded into the form's datasource, the combo box displays no value, but then upon clicking it you must select a value.  The form/combobox will never let you change back to a blank item (to represent "null" on the customer object).

I don't want "dummy rows" in the database, and currently do this by adding a dummy object, and nulling it out in a submit event (not clean!).

Is it possible to do this cleanly, keeping with the nullable primary key?

Comment: Perhaps you should post links to the said questions (on SO) or external resources on the web.

Comment: Just a suggestion, how about making your "types" an enum with one of the values being "Unspecified"? I know this isn't an answer, but you should be using enums anyway...

Comment: In some situations enums might be a solution, but they are not if the data comes from datasources. For example think about a product configurator for a car - there might be a combobox with all available navigation systems. In the database the table Car will have a nullable foreign key to the table NavigationSystems. So you want to bind the combobox to the NavigationSystems table but still allow null if the user decides not to buy a navigation system. It might be a solution to add a new row "No navigation system" and make the foreign key non-nullable - but this has disadvantages, too.

Comment: I wish I add 10 upvotes to this question. It highlights such a monumental oversight in the whole data binding infrastructure. The developers of which clearly never tried it themselves very much. I'm also surprised it only attracts two answers, the accepted of which is very opaque.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The datasource which is used to bind to the Type combo, could have 1 more entry with NULL value in it.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeID   Name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1        Business
2        Government
-1       NULL
```

You could store -1 for Customer who doesn't have a type (if it is allowed that a customer need not have a type).

Comment: I don't want -1 in my database.  I want null.

Comment: Dont store -1 in the DB. If the user chooses blank item from the DB (hence the selectedItem's value will be -1) - store null in DB if thats the case

Comment: @shahkalpesh How do you propose we tell data binding to translate a -1 to a null?

Comment: @ProfK: I don't recommend using data bindings, datasets (all the stuff that MS throws which is good for demo, people use it and find inadequate). Does `CurrencyManager` help in this case?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I will have a look, thanks. I find data binding quite adequate in most cases, though. I don't have many issues besides this one.

Answer (score 0):

Additional links and resources concerning nullable databinding:

I've been told and so far it has panned out, that you should have a layer of business objects in between your database datasource and your UI where you could just add an item as shahkalpesh recommends without concern of it going into the database.

Jez Humble has some information on binding nullable types at the bottom of this [post and in comments](http://blog.jezhumble.net/?p=3) Where it suggests binding to nullable types is doable if "you explicitly set the DataSourceUpdateMode to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged".

Another article on databinding Nullable types: The Joy of Code - [Databinding and Nullable types in WinForms.NET](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Databinding_and_Nullable_types_in_WinForms.NET.aspx)

Maybe this code for binding a nullable DateTimePicker could help you find addditional solutions for this or other nullable issues.

Also check out [Dan Hannan](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/danhanan/archive/2007/01/21/10847.aspx) for the source of where I came up with my extension method.

```
/// <summary>
    /// From BReusable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dtp"></param>
    /// <param name="dataSource"></param>
    /// <param name="valueMember"></param>
    /// <remarks>With help from Dan Hanan at http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/danhanan/archive/2007/01/21/10847.aspx</remarks>
    public static void BindNullableValue(this DateTimePicker dateTimePicker, BindingSource dataSource, String valueMember,bool showCheckBox)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value", dataSource, valueMember, true);

        //OBJECT PROPERTY --> CONTROL VALUE
        binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            Binding b = sender as Binding;

            if (b != null)
            {
                DateTimePicker dtp = (binding.Control as DateTimePicker);
                if (dtp != null)
                {
                    if (e.Value == null)
                    {

                        dtp.ShowCheckBox = showCheckBox;
                        dtp.Checked = false;

                        // have to set e.Value to SOMETHING, since it's coming in as NULL
                        // if i set to DateTime.Today, and that's DIFFERENT than the control's current
                        // value, then it triggers a CHANGE to the value, which CHECKS the box (not ok)
                        // the trick - set e.Value to whatever value the control currently has. 
                        // This does NOT cause a CHANGE, and the checkbox stays OFF.

                        e.Value = dtp.Value;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dtp.ShowCheckBox = showCheckBox;
                        dtp.Checked = true;
                        // leave e.Value unchanged - it's not null, so the DTP is fine with it.
                    }

                }

            }
        });
        // CONTROL VALUE --> OBJECT PROPERTY
        binding.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            // e.value is the formatted value coming from the control. 
            // we change it to be the value we want to stuff in the object.
            Binding b = sender as Binding;

            if (b != null)
            {
                DateTimePicker dtp = (b.Control as DateTimePicker);
                if (dtp != null)
                {
                    if (dtp.Checked == false)
                    {
                        dtp.ShowCheckBox = showCheckBox;
                        dtp.Checked = false;
                        e.Value = (Nullable<DateTime>)null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DateTime val = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Value);
                        e.Value = val;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(binding);

    }
```

Comment: Every post you link to and your answer all involve format and parse. I may be a bit slow today, but how does this address a ComboBox problem?

Comment: because the answer shows what the question asks, how to bind a nullable value to combo box without having a `-1` magic number

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to restore the combo to blank and the value to null, just press Ctrl+0 when editing the row.

*It took me two days of frantic research and heart attack risk just to find this out hidden in a small post somewhere.*